# How to mix / intersperse two .npy files?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two `.npy` files that both contain a ndarray with shape `(1_000_000, 833)` (1M inputs for a neural network with 833 input neurons), however the exact shape should not matter except that it is the same among the two files.

I want to create two new `.npy` files that are taken from both files, one after the other. Let's say the first file contains `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and the second one `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`, then the new first file should contain `[1, a, 2, b, 3, c]` and the new second one `[4, d, 5, e, 6, f]`- the size of the files and the contents should remain the same, only its arrangement (and arrangement among the files) should change.

How could I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to concatenate the arrays in 2D, then [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html?highlight=ravel#numpy.ndarray.ravel) in Fortran order:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
B = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

C = np.vstack([A, B]).ravel(order='F')
```

Or:

```
C = np.empty(A.shape[0]+B.shape[0], dtype=B.dtype)
C[::2] = A
C[1::2] = B
```

Output:

```
array(['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e', '6', 'f'],
      dtype='<U21')
```

###### multiple arrays:

```
l = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])+10*i for i in range(50)]

# option 1
out = np.vstack(l).ravel(order='F')

# option 2
out = np.empty(sum(map(len, l)))
for i, a in enumerate(l):
    out[i::len(l)] = a
```

Comment: Does the `vstack` and `ravel` method also work for more than two arrays?

Comment: Yes, if they have the same shape. I can update the other answer to be generic if you like

Comment: This answer is great, but unfortunately requires loading all files into memory (tbf you can't be blamed as I didn't explicity state this as a requirement). My goal is to intersperse 16 files, each about 1GB, this way, and I only have about 6GB RAM to work with. I will probably first try to do it manually (i.e. iterate over an mmap mapped object and create the files one-by-one) or even write a custom solution in Rust using the `npyz` crate. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: If you only have 6GB, I don't think there is a way to use numpy as you would need to have the full merge in memory at some point.

Comment: I don't think so - I said that I wanted to create the same amount of files I had from the beginning. So I create 16 file readers and read 1 value from all of them until I have 1M values, and then save this to the hard disk and free the memory. If I'm not mistaken this way I could intersperse any number of files with just 1GB (+ some buffering overhead) of RAM.

Comment: But you're right in that I can't use numpy - I'm now going to use [npyz](https://lib.rs/npyz), which allows to read .npy files that don't fit into memory.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I hope it works!